# Server statistics (processor usage and bandwidth usage)

Tags: apache-2.2, nic

How can I find out how much of a load my webserver is under?  I tried `top` but I don't know how to interpret the information it's showing me for CPU.  While top may give me the CPU usage I also need to find out the bandwidth (load on the NIC) to see if the server is being overwhelmed or not.  I tried `netstat` but all I could see is what the active connections are.

I don't know much about serve maintenance, I'm a programmer and my sysadmin is on jury duty.  Any hints are much appreciated.

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu server, with a few small PHP scripts.  The majority of the traffic is some large binary files which are being downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For processor usage install htop:

```
$ sudo apt-get install htop
$ htop
```

For bandwidth usage install iptaf:

```
$ sudo apt-get install iptraf
$ iptraf
```

But I suggest [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/), [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/).

Comment: Could you suggest which of these network statistics trackers would take the least resources?  If the server is already under heavy load I don't want to put a bulky daemon on it.

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have iptraf in it's repsoitories.  I made sure to do apt-get update also.

Comment: If you already use Apache, Cacti/Munin take the least resources. Because, it doesn't use database.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/lucid/iptraf

Comment: iptraf is a really nice monitor with a simple GUI, recommend for quick, temporary monitorings

Answer (score 0):

i second htop as a replacement for top.
also i like bmon for live network useage checks, IIRC its in the ubuntu repros too.